# Determining diameter of strands of twisted rope

Tags: applications, solid-geometry

Twisted ropes are made by taking 3 strands of smaller rope and twisting them together tightly, by coiling the strands in the same direction, as opposed to braided rope, which requires strands to be woven together.

Is it possible, given the diameter of the twisted rope, to determine the diameter of the individual strands of rope, assuming that the strands all have the same diameter? If not, is there any additional information that is needed to make such a determination, or is this generally not possible without examining the actual physical rope?

Comment: The cross section of the final rope is three equal circles touching each other externally. Physical examination is not necessary, but a  little imagination is required.